# The meaning of Drop-off as a noun

Tags: phrase-meaning

> In mobster movies, the criminals always refer to a secret drop-off where they make illegal transactions.

What does a secret "**drop-off**" mean?
Does it mean a secret "**place**"? Because it relates to mobster movies I think it could have a special meaning that I do not get it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is used in many mob or gangster movies, Yes. This is because a *"drop off"*, as the name goes, is where you *"drop off"* something.

The Free dictionary defines '[drop-off](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/drop-off)' as:

> A **designated place** where people or things can be left.

Additionally, it is also the shortened version of *"drop-off point"*. If it's a mob or gangster movie, the *"drop-off"* will be the location where certain things, (say drugs? ) will be delivered, from where the designated receiver can collect it from. The person or an object that is the target of discussion will be left here, and the people who drop them off should leave as soon as the drop-off is complete. (That's clearly the golden rule in a mobster/ gangster/ drug lord based transaction).

for example,

**Carlos**: Boss, we have the "package". Where are you seniōre?
**Boss**: I'm at the '*drop*', you numb skull.
**Carlos**: All right, see you soon boss. Emilio Rodriguez Esteban Carlos Out.

**PS, *"Drop"*, *"Drop-off"*, *"Drop-off point"* means the same when it comes to gangster slang.**

Comment: I've also heard _drop point_ used for this; e.g.: _When the operative didn't see you at the drop point, he moved on._

Comment: +1, but note the term is not limited to criminals. Charities often have "drop offs" where people can leave clothing and the like to be given to the poor. My auto mechanic has a "key drop off" where, if you bring your car for repairs after they are closed, you can deposit the keys in the slot so they can work on the car the next day. Etc.